# Setting the URL for the pagination numbers

Tags: php

I have some problems generating the url i want to put in my pagination numbers. I'm setting the url inside a class with

```
$this->url = rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], " /");
```

then inside another class I'm setting the href value on the pagination number with

```
echo "<a class='active' href='".$this->page->url."/".$i."/'>".$i."</a>";
```

So when i now navigate to my page the url is like this

> localhost/designv2/blog/

Then when i click on number 1 in the pagination i get

> localhost/designv2/blog/1/

But, then when i click on number 2 in the pagination i get

> localhost/designv2/blog/1/2

And if i click on number 3 i get

> localhost/designv2/blog/1/2/3

Why, does it keep on adding numbers to the url instead of replacing the old number?

I could split up the url, run it through a for loop and remove the last parameter but I'm using this url for other things on my pages aswell so i cant just remove the last parameter.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before appending `ID` at the last in url, check and remove `ID` if exist.

Instead

```
$this->url = rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], " /");
```

Replace last occurence of `/\/[0-9]\/$/` here (`/1/` or `/2/`) to `/`.Try something like this

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$regex = '/\/[0-9]\/$/';
$this->url = preg_replace($regex, '/', $url);
```

[Live demo](https://eval.in/948521)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
  echo "<a class='active' href='/designv2/blog/".$i."/'>".$i."</a>";
```

Comment: Yeah that works but, then it wont be dynamic. I'm also using the pagination more then 1 place so the url is not always /designv2/blog/2 and can also be /design/blog/sort/tag/php/2 etc.